# How to implement my code to specific unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

```
def function(n):

    if n % 2 != 0:
        print('weird')
    elif n % 2 == 0 and n in range(2, 5):
        print('not weird')
    elif n % 2 == 0 and n in range(6, 20):
        print('weird')
    elif n % 2 == 0 and n > 20:
        print('not weird')
    return n

# while True:
#     n = int(input('enter the number: '))
#     function(n)
import unittest
class Test_function(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_function(self):
        self.assertEqual(function(2), 'not weird')
```

I'm trying to test the code while executing the code nothing is showing in output.
This is the way of writing code to test code? can anyone suggest how to write unit test code?

Comment: Note that best practice is : the method should return a string, and the caller decide what to do : in execution "print it", in test "test it", that helps

Comment: @arzro I think you didn't explain clearly your comment is not related to my code at all... I'm asking how to test my code

Comment: See the duplicate link for how to  test your code

Comment: then my comment is completely related to your code : the good practtice would be to RETURN the string and not printing it, then the main code would print, and the test would check its value

Comment: @azro I don't understand that duplicate link, Can you explain please to me how to test code using my code for example? I search google it's all simple code examples are there.

Comment: What don't you understand ? Use the same code, then `assertEqual(capturedOutput.getvalue(), "not weird")`